# Can I use ogr from OSGeo4W in python env?

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo4w

I use QGIS and therefore also OSGeo4W.
At the moment I am writing a script that use ogr in python. I need a virtual environment for because it is going to be deployed on a server (which also has OSGeo4W). After creating a virtual env (python -m venv venv) then I cannot import ogr as I would do from the OSGeo4W shell `from osgeo import ogr`. I am a windows user, so is the server.

I have been reading many post about issues using/installing ogr in python but at the moment I am completely confused, I . I am not a very experienced python user, and setting up the dependencies appear to be the hardest bit yet.
This post is similar to what I want to do [Use OGR and GDAL in Python outside OSGEO4W shell](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201752/use-ogr-and-gdal-in-python-outside-osgeo4w-shell) but the link in the post to binaries include mapserver which I am not interested in. Any advice?

Comment: Despite the name of the directory you can install just GDAL. For example this GDAL core installer installs just GDAL core features http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1911-x64-gdal-3-0-0-mapserver-7-4-0/gdal-300-1911-x64-core.msi. But if you download some other package that contains also MapServer binaries then just don't run MapServer.

Comment: `I use QGIS and therefore also OSGeo4W.` therefore also doesn't necessarily follow, you don't need OSGeo4W to use QGIS.

Comment: That is true, I just wanted to point out that I am aware that using OSGeo4W is an option, was thinking maybe I can "reuse" ogr that come with OSGeo4W in my python env. But as far as I can tell, that is not possible.

Comment: @user30184 I installed the suggested download and I can now run ogr from cmd. But I can still not use it in my "regular" python or python in my created venv. Am I misunderstanding the use of it or is it still not working? I have tried import ogr and from osgeo import ogr. Giving me ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo' or ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ogr'

Comment: You must also install the GDAL Python bindings from the same download page. There is also a note on that page `Note: In order to have the bindings work the location of the core components must be included manually in the PATH environment variable.`. Unfortunately I do not know what those core components are.

Comment: I followed the instructions from one of the answers in the link I included to from the other post which include adding to Path unfortunately it did not do the trick. I will keep trying. Thank you